# Apache deny access all files in a directory while allowing access to sub directories

Tags: apache2

I may have asked this in the wrong site -- so I am trying my question here.

Like to deny access to all files within a directory; while allowing access to files within the sub directories. I thought I had this licked until I notice a denied access error under apache logs for one sub directory.

`/www/domain.com/public_html/directory`

*In this folder deny access to all files*

`/www/domain.com/public_html/directory/subdirectories`

*In the sub directories allow full access to all files which include jpeg, jpg and index.php files*

The sub directories are dynamic albums and contain only jpg images and an index.php file for processing and nothing else.

Here is what I am using that seemed good to go until I seen an permission denied error on one of the images with the subs. Which is there and should have full access.

```
<Directory "/www/domain.com/public_html/directory">
   AllowOverride None
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from All
   <FilesMatch ".jpg|.jpeg|index.php">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </FilesMatch>
   ErrorDocument 403 /
   ErrorDocument 404 /
</Directory>
<DirectoryMatch "/www/domain.com/public_html/directory/[A-Za-z0-9]{6}">
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from All
   ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</DirectoryMatch>
```